# Spark SQL nested query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following spark sql query

```
SELECT count(*),
       channel
FROM channelusage a
WHERE a.starttime>= windowstarttime
  AND a.endtime <= windowendtime
GROUP BY channel
```

I have to generate these counts for 10 windows. Currently I use a while loop to generate the windowstarttime and windowendtime.

What I want to do is - I want to generate the windows in the sql query itself something like a nested sql similar to this -

```
SELECT count(*),
       channel
FROM channelusage a
WHERE (nested query logic)
GROUP BY channel
```

so that I get a output similar to this

```
windowstarttime | windowentime | channel | count
11:00:01        | 11:00:10     | ABC     |2
11:00:11        | 11:00:20     | ABC     |4
11:00:21        | 11:00:30     | NBC     |10
11:00:31        | 11:00:40     | CNN     |5
```

Comment: What is your input data set?

Comment: input is required here